# can cucumber take screenshot for every step

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, cucumber, selenium-grid

There is a functionality in JBehave with which you can get screenshot after every step is executed. There is something similar if one runs code with BrowserStack.
Is there some code we can use, while using Cucumber and Selenium WebDriver?
If so, can you please provide a link to a tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an AfterStep.  From the [wiki](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks):

```
AfterStep do |scenario|
  # Do something after each step.
end
```

Comment: Interesting... I tried to to implement it with Cucumber-Java v1.2.2 and 1.2.4, but I am unable to gain access to the class library. @AfterStep does not work for me with Cucumber-Java.